# Using Windows named pipes from inside activeX control - Possible?

Tags: winapi, activex, pipe, named-pipes

I am starting to design a DMO to run from inside a windows media player activeX control in Internet Explorer.

is there any reason why using windows named pipes from inside the DMO wouldn't work?

user permissions/privilages/ kernel mode stuff?

Thanks :)
Roey

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but I can't think of any particular reason it could not work.  However, keep in mind that starting with Vista Internet Explorer runs as a low integrity level processes so any pipe you connect to will need to have it's access control set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this from a FireBreath plugin (activex control on IE, npapi on others) and the only thing you need to keep in mind is that activex controls in IE are often running in low integrity mode, so you need to make sure you set the ACL mask on the pipe correctly.  As long as you have it configured correctly, it works fine.